# Angular 6 Validate child component and show an inline error message on button click from the parent component

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a parent component and a child component.
I want to validate and show the inline error message in the child component field when the button is clicked from the parent component.

Here is the stackblitz url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-vo1axj

thanks
SJT

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Input to get value from parent 
you can learn more about it here 
https://angular.io/api/core/Input

```js
<Child data = "data"> // in parent html

@Input() data: string; // use can get value in child using this
```

> You can then send data from child to parent using Eventemitter

learn more about Event Emitter here
https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter